# WAMP limit log files size

Tags: apache, logging, wamp, error-log, access-log

Is there any functionality in wamp to limit the access and error log to 20 MB? i.e. it should be truncated after 20 MB.

Answer (score 0):

usually (on linux) the log are managed by another system (for example a log rotate), it's not apache which manage them itself - if you understand french [someone did logrotate.bat and shared it on the wampserver forum](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?1,73910) - thus you can use a log rotate system of windows too

Hope this could help